# Erro com método abstract

Tags: c#

Bom dia, alguém sabe porque o compilador continua acusando o erro dizendo que o método não está declarado como abstract, mas mesmo eu tendo declarado?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o link do Repl.it: https://repl.it/@WellingtonMazon/Calculo-de-triangulo
E os códigos abaixo:

```
using System;

namespace triangulo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Retangulo r = new Retangulo();
            r.Largura = 8.3;
            r.Altura = 3.5;
            Console.WriteLine("Área do retângulo: {0}", r.CalculaArea());

            Triangulo t = new Triangulo();
            t.Largura = 8.3;
            t.Altura = 3.5;
            Console.WriteLine("Área do triângulo: {0}", t.CalculaArea());

        }
    }
}


using System;
namespace triangulo
{
    abstract class FiguraGeometrica
    {
        public double Largura = 0;
        public double Altura = 0;
        public abstract double CalculaArea()
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}


using System;
namespace triangulo
{
    class Retangulo : FiguraGeometrica
    {
        public override double CalculaArea()
        {
            return Largura * Altura;
        }
    }
    class Triangulo : FiguraGeometrica
    {
        public override double CalculaArea()
        {
            return Largura * Altura / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parece que o pessoal do .NET gosta de errar esse tipo de mensagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por se tratar de um método abstrato ele não deve ter implementação, ou seja o método apenas é declarado mas não faz nada para que que a classe que herdar ela seja obrigada a implementar.

Para resolver retire o corpo dela, para que fique assim:

```
    public abstract double CalculaArea();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, estou aprendendo a programar. Obrigado por me ajudar.

Comment: Estamos as ordens!

Answer (score 1):

Todos os trechos desta respostas foram tirados desta fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract

Como uma declaração de método abstrato não fornece nenhuma implementação real, não há nenhum corpo de método, a declaração do método simplesmente termina com um ponto e vírgula e não há chaves ({ }) após a assinatura. Por exemplo:

```
public abstract void MyMethod();
```

Uma classe abstrata que implementa uma interface pode mapear os métodos de interface em métodos abstratos. Por exemplo:

```
interface I
{
    void M();
}
abstract class C : I
{
    public abstract void M();
}
```